# ERROR: Loading object was of wrong class

Tags: .net, nhibernate, model-view-controller

I have an MVC/Nhibernate app that is giving me the below.

> [WrongClassException: Object with id: f7eab616-76b2-4602-8643-b4466e91a33f was not of the specified subclass: AgileThought.ERP.Domain.CRM.Client (loading object was of wrong class [AgileThought.ERP.Domain.HR.SalesRepresentative])]
>      NHibernate.Loader.Loader.InstanceAlreadyLoaded(IDataReader rs, Int32 i, IEntityPersister persister, EntityKey key, Object obj, LockMode lockMode, ISessionImplementor session) +229

I believe from the stack trace that the line **NHibernate.Loader.Loader.InstanceAlreadyLoaded** says the object is already loaded.

The problem is that the object may be of a few types which have the same GUID.
IE

a Client Inherits from a Person

a Employee Inherits from a Person

a Sales Rep Inherits from Employee

In my dev environment, my user account has all three entity types.

The problem is that now when I do a search on a Client, it sees the GUID from a Sales Rep and assumes that I want my Sales Rep object.
The next line of my code fails as it is expecting a Client list, but one object is a Sales Rep.

I have seen several similar issue in searching but they all seem to revolve around using a discriminator. I have a seperate table for each of these sub classes, just listing the GUID and any extra properties.
I have also seen this error reported with hibernate (java) as a code error, but the article said it was corrected in Nhibernate Port wtih a broken link to the issue.

The Nhibernate API query specifies my object type it should be getting, so I am not sure what else I can do.
Is there a way to force a fresh query?

The situation is unlikely to occur in real life, but I am concerned that I my login cant be both a client and a sales rep under the current situation, I have no doubt this will cause greater issue elswhere in the application where some other person types will be used.
(Each type has a few seperate properties, I dont want to use a disctiminator or user Roles to specifiy there person type.)

Any advise would be much appreciated.

Please find code below.

Search Method:

```
 public IEnumerable<Client> NewContacts(Guid userGUID)
    { 
         SalesRepresentative rep = new SalesRepresentativeRepository().GetById(userGUID);
         List<Client> result = new List<Client>();
         using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
         {
             foreach (var i in rep.Projects)
             {
                 ICriteria criteriaPerson = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Client));
                 criteriaPerson.CreateAlias("ProjectsOfInterest","p");
                 criteriaPerson.Add(Expression.Eq("p.EntityGUID", i.EntityGUID));
                 //Distinct
                 criteriaPerson.SetResultTransformer(new NHibernate.Transform.DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer());

                 result.AddRange(criteriaPerson.List<Client>());
             }
             return result.Distinct();
         }
    }
```

The object is loaded already loaded as a Sales Rep on the line:

```
SalesRepresentative rep = new SalesRepresentativeRepository().GetById(userGUID);
```

The issue is on the line:

```
result.AddRange(criteriaPerson.List<Client>());
```

because one of my clients is me, the Sales Rep.

Originally this code didn't have a loop around the project, but an inner join via alias's.
This was just one attempt to find an answer by taking it out of the query, but it had the same result.

```
                 ICriteria criteriaPerson = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Client));
                 criteriaPerson.CreateAlias("ProjectsOfInterest", "p");
                 criteriaPerson.CreateAlias("ProjectsOfInterest.SalesRepresentatives", "rep");
                 criteriaPerson.Add(Expression.Eq("rep.EntityGUID", userGUID));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fell in this same error today (for the second time actually) and I finally realized what's the issue here.

I don't knwo abount others ORM but using nHibernate you can't share an Id over two different classes (subclasses). That's not the way inheritance is supposed to be in nHibernate. Table-per-class hierarchy is meant to have separate tables to specify a parent table (in your issue you are trying the opposite).

All this actually make sense since to access Client or Employee you actually refer to the Person Id (at first I didn't paid attention to this but now is totally clear).

The solution is to refactor the domain model and change the relationship between you classes from as "is-a" to a "has-a" relationship and expose common properties (if needed) via an interface.